# _firebaseAuth.updateProfile missing after firebase_auth plugin upgrade to 0.6.2+1

Tags: firebase, flutter

_firebaseAuth.updateProfile missing after firebase_auth plugin upgrade to 0.6.2+1

Upgrade firebase_auth plugin from 0.5.20 to 0.6.2+1 in pubspec.yaml and suddenly cannot compile my Flutter app.
The reason? updateProfile Method is missing.
Why? What happened?

Cannot compile at all:

```
Compiler message:
lib/Screens/Profile/index.dart:549:20: Error: The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::Auth'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'updateProfile'.
              auth.updateProfile(myInfo);
                   ^
lib/services/authentication.dart:164:25: Error: The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::FirebaseAuth'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'updateProfile'.
    await _firebaseAuth.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
```

Comment: the method is available : https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/firebase_auth.dart 
Try flutter clean command

Comment: Please run `flutter clean`, then `flutter run` and post the output in your question.

Comment: I have done flutter clean few times and still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it is not compiling.

> 0.6.0 Added support for updatePassword in FirebaseUser. Breaking Change Moved updateEmail and updateProfile to FirebaseUser. This
>   brings the firebase_auth package inline with other implementations and
>   documentation.

The method has moved...

Answer (score 0):

The Method is not Compiling because it's moved to class FireBaseUser 
so the Solution:

-Create instance from FirebaseUser:

```
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
userUpdateInfo.displayName = 'name';
userUpdateInfo.photoUrl = "Image link";
user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
```